# Create a date measure as a filter on power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, measure

I need to set a date measure as a filter in filter pane.My measure is as below,

```
Measure 2 =
VAR minDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( DateTable[Date] ) )
VAR maxDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) )
RETURN
    IF (
        MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) >= minDate
            && MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) <= maxDate,
        minDate & " " & maxDate
    )
```

The out put is minimum date and maximum date in date table.Is there a way to do this? Simply i need to set this measure as a filter So the user can tick this if he wants to see the data under this dates.

Thanks

Comment: In order to identify those dates, I'll simply use a boolean calculated column (made in PowerQuery or DAX), then you can simply include/exclude those dates by filtering on this additional column.
Will something like this work? if no, can you provide some more information?

Comment: Hi Giovanni, I think that would work.Can you help me with the calculated column? How it should be calculated?